# Meteor CollectionFS: userId param for Download allow/deny function

Tags: javascript, file-upload, meteor, amazon-s3, collectionfs

This problem is documented in the issue [here](https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS/issues/711) but has not got a response yet.

The documentation says that the the download allow/deny permission function gets the userId and fileObj but when I tried this, the userId is just a value `false`.

```
UserImages.deny({
  download: function(userId, fileObj) {
    // use userId to determine if download should be allowed.
    console.log(userId); // <=== This for some reason always prints `false` even when the user is logged in
   return false;
  }
});
```

Looking at the issue, this might be a bug but I can't confirm.

Comment: I'm using CollectionFS, too and I am using the userId parameter for securing downloads and inserts. So far I cannot confirm the problem you see. Is it exclusively for deny() or also for allow()? Can you show us your download implementation? And obviously userId can only have a user id if the download was triggered client-side from a logged in user.

Comment: @JeyDWork It is not exclusive for deny. It happens for both deny and allow. And that is my download implementation in its entirety for now. I realized I was not getting the proper userId so I did not add any other security before I solved this issue. And yes, I checked if the user is logged in too.

Comment: But since as you say, you are not getting this issue, I must be doing something wrong. Not sure though. I just used the regular things like `cfs:standard`, `cfs:s3`, `cfs:gridfs`.. Nothing too different from their examples. I will try to dig in some more.

Comment: @JeyDWork I'm curious are you using the S3 adapter?